# How to change site name only in backend?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a Wordpress network with 3 sites.

I use each site for a different language of the same website. Thus the name (the title) of each site is exactly the same! Let's say I have: *My Great Website* in english, *My Great Website* in french and *My Great Website* in german.

Even if for me is quite easy to understand which site I am working on, for other editors may be very confusing. So working in the back-end, when I want to choose a site from the dropdown I see all the same title.

I wonder if there is a simple hack or a plugin just to change the name of each site only in the My sites dropdown. Or maybe if I have missed some options in my backend.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Am new to multisite. But as per my understanding we can upload separate plugins to all the sites.

You can try adding 'AG Custom Admin' Plugin. This plugin is having an option to customize dashboard, admin bar etc. You can change the logos for three different websites.

Comment: Good call @Anjana Shyamlal as AG Custom Admin is a cool plugin. Unfortunately I experience some trouble on multisite when I active it.